# AJP monitoring in Apache 2.2 and Wildfly

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring, ajp

I need to monitor the AJP connections Apache 2.2 has with Wildfly 8.2.1, but it seems that jboss-cli does not have this metric and I don't know if this is possible in Apache.

Any ideas?